# how to create request on the server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am currently creating a request in the client side and reading it in my node.js. It works great when it is in production build and is deployed, but I need to keep changing

`var request = new Request('/api/test', {`

line to

`var request = new Request('http://localhost:3001/api/test', {`

all the time in in development since the client is running on port 3000.

Is there a better way to create the request in the server side?

client side:

```
var request = new Request('/api/test', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' }),
                body: JSON.stringify(user)
            });
```

server side

```
app.post('/api/test ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). The MDN docs will explain this better than I would here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in react app and set host variables in development.env and production.env .